# Simple MIDI File Creator

Tags: c#, midi

I've got an array of a MIDINote class that I wrote. Each MIDINote has the MIDI note number, as well as the onset, offset, and duration of that note. Now I want to create a MIDI file out of these notes. It should be monophonic, which means it should only have one track. And the volume of all notes should be the same. I've already taken a look at other solutions; however, none of them seem to do what I want.

Comment: Which solutions have you already looked at? If you don't tell us, you're likely to get pointed to the same solutions again. Other than that, have you looked into the MIDI specification? The MIDI file format isn't so difficult to understand or, in particular, to write. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Use Sanfords Midi Toolkit: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the record to file sample application of the [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com) library. Although the file handling may appear to be complex - that is because it is build on a generic chunk-file library, but its use is relatively simple.

Do note however that MIDI works with Note-On and Note-Off events, so you have to convert your note duration times to a note-off event.

Hope it helps.